# How to show date and time together on x-axis of a plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which plots the expected output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import re

Time = []
station12SRV = []
station18SRV = []

with open('Book2.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:

        datetime_format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
        date_time_data = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],datetime_format)
        Time.append(date_time_data)
        station12SRV.append(float(row[1]))
        station18SRV.append(float(row[2]))

plt.plot(Time,station12SRV, label='Tracker Station 12')
plt.plot(Time,station18SRV, label='Tracker Station 18')

plt.xlabel('Date & Time')
plt.ylabel('Pressure (Torr)')
plt.yscale('log')
#plt.title('SRV Plot vs Time')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('trackers_srv.pdf')
#plt.show()
```

However, on the plot, the x-axis doesn't show the date and time together, and only shows the time:

[image: the plot]

How do I get it to show both the date and time together on the x-axis? Thanks.

Comment: The sentence "please ask a new question." in the duplicate note is to be understood in the following way: When asking a new question, this new question should be based on the information gathered from the duplicate post. Please **do not ask the same question twice**.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to get date and time formatted on the x axis is to put your data in a Pandas data frame and use `df.plot()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(3)
import pandas as pd

# Generate sample data
Time = pd.date_range('3/1/19 12:00 AM', '3/3/19 12:00 AM', freq='1H')
n = len(Time)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tracker Station 12': np.random.rand(n), 'Tracker Station 18': 1+np.random.rand(n), 'Time': Time})
df = df.set_index('Time')

df.plot()
plt.ylabel('Pressure (Torr)')
plt.yscale('log')
```

[image: Plot with date on x axis]